# como fazer o react renderizar uma tabela

Tags: javascript, html, react, for, dom

Estou tentando fazer uma tabela , 5 de altura por 7 largura , dentro do react , porém , quando eu tentou rodar o 2° `for loop`  ele não reconhece e acaba não fazendo a ação , obg pela ajuda S2

```
function Principal(){

var altura = 5;
var largura = 7;
const desing = [];

for(var i ; i < altura ; i++){
  desing.push(<tr>);
  for(var a ; a , largura ; a++){
      desing.push(<td>"a"</td>)
  }
  desing.push(</tr>);
}
return(
  <div id='calendario'>
   {desing}
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: não entendi sua pergunta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Componentes do React não são strings HTML, como se faria num jQuery da vida.
Você deve usar `map` sempre que for fazer uma lista de componentes de tamanho arbitrário.

```js
function Principal() {
  const altura = 5;
  const largura = 7;

  // cria Array de 0 até n - 1:
  const linhas = Array.from(Array(altura).keys());
  const colunas = Array.from(Array(largura).keys());

  return (
    <div id="calendario">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {linhas.map((linha) => (
            <tr key={linha}>
              {colunas.map((coluna) => (
                <td
                  key={coluna}
                  style={{ border: "solid #ccc" }}
                >{`(${linha}, ${coluna})`}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <Principal/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Comment: Rodrigo nos temos em nosso site como renderizar componentes REACT, fiz a edição e coloquei como exemplo, apesar que poderia ter montado um estado nesse componente, fazer assim solto pode trazer problemas futuros.

Comment: muito obrigado , mas ainda tenho uma duvida.Se nós colocarmos as chaves entre os elementos do JSX ele ira executar o código como javascript, certo? .Então , por que se eu colocar o for..loop dentro das chaves ele não executa ?Sendo que eu consigo chamar variaveis e fazer até expressões simples como 3 + 7

Comment: Dentro das chaves é permitido colocar apenas uma expressão que resulta num valor, algo que poderia ser atribuído a uma variável antes do "return". Uma variável não pode ser igual a um loop. Também é permitido usar os métodos .reduce ou .filter, por exemplo.